# How to play jQuery Reel to a specific frame and stop there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

jQuery Reel (http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) is an excellent jQuery plugin for creating nice 360-views of things.

There are events you can trigger to play, stop and pause the animation, and also to detect what frame you are currently on (`.reel("frame")`) but I can't really work out how to put them together to create a link which plays the reel of a specific frame, and then stops. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

You can `"play"` it, bind to `"frameChange"` event to check for the target frame and when that is reached, `"stop"` it. Something like this:

```
$('#your_reel_image')
.trigger('play')
.bind('frameChange', function(){
    if ($(this).reel('frame') == target_frame){
        $(this).trigger('stop');
    }
});
```

Just be aware of the fact, that on slower devices like mobiles, some frames may be skipped in order to keep up with the required animation speed.

You also receive the `frame` as third event handler argument to save yourself the additional `.reel()` call inside the handler, so the above can be refactored to:

```
$('#your_reel_image')
.trigger('play')
.bind('frameChange', function(e, depr_frame, frame){
    if (frame == target_frame){
        $(this).trigger('stop');
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Since version 1.3, you can replace the above solution with calling just:

```
$('#your_reel_image').trigger('reach', target_frame);
```

Reel will animate the shortest path towards the given frame and stop there.

Comment: Thanks for this great plugin Petr! Is there a straightforward way to increase the speed whilst moving to a specific frame? I've tried reinitialising reel with a new speed, but it of course resets to the first frame, which isn't what I intend.

Comment: Actually there is. Send new speed when triggering the [`"play"` event](http://test.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel/docs/jquery.reel.html#play-Event) like so `.trigger('play', 0.5)`. Refer to the [issue #110](https://github.com/pisi/Reel/issues/110) on Github.

Comment: Regarding the functionality of the `'reach'` event: It will attempt to play to the target frame at the current speed, which, if not specified, will be 0 and thus not work. `.trigger` requires that extra attributes be in an array, so you would call `$('#your_reel_image').trigger('reach', [target_frame, speed]);`